# Filter IEnumerable<object> based on whether string property contains any string value of another List<string>

Tags: c#, linq

I have an IEnumerable collection of custom objects types which contain a string property in JSON format.  I also have a List collection which I need to use in order to filter the IEnumerable.  I want to remove all items from the IEnumerable where the string property contains any string value from the List collection.  I can pull this off by creating a temporary list and doing some looping but I'm looking for a more elegant solution and I haven't been successful yet.

```
foreach (var faction in excludedFactions)
{
    cardsVM.Cards = repository.Cards.ToList()
        .RemoveAll(c => c.Factions.Contains(faction));
}
```

This is one thing that I've tried.  I've been playing around with LINQ statements for the last two hours and I can't make it work.  If anyone could point me in the right direction (a proper function for my requirements) that would be more than appreciated.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I can only post every 40 minutes, but your comment has been noted.  Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it´s a review and thus should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a `HashSet<string>` of excluded factions, then use this set to filter your cards:

```
var excludedFactionSet = new HashSet<string>(excludedFactions);
cardsVM.Cards = repository.Cards
    .Where(c => !excludedFactionSet.Contains(c.Factions))
    .ToList();
```

Note that using `excludedFactions` directly is also possible. However, using `HashSet<string>` makes `Contains(f)` check work in constant, rather than linear, time.